# Print the class name of derived class using inherited function

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is there any way to print the class name of a derived class with an inherited function without overriding that function in the derived class?

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void print() { printf("%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
};

class B : public A {};

int main() {
    B b;

    b.print() // should yield "B::print()" but yields "A::print()"
}
```

I'm asking so that I can just call up `A::print()` in an overridden function to print the attributes related to the parent class, but include the current class name.

Comment: class B has no `print()`

Comment: If you want to ask, at runtime, "what's the most-derived type of `this`" then you can use `typeid(this).name()` (only works with polymorphic types). You may have to use a compiler-specific utility function to demangle this name. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6781a148e7daea77)

Comment: @cdhowie i would have never thought, that this can work, because i thought the typeid operator is resolved at compile time. That raises new questions, how typeid is implemented and how the type information is packed into the binary.

Comment: @OutOfBound Consider, for example, that `dynamic_cast<void *>(foo)` will return a pointer to the most-derived object type of the object pointed to by `foo`, provided that `foo` points at a polymorphic object. So in this way, we can obtain a pointer to "the real object" at runtime even without any special type information. From there, the [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) system (of which `typeid()` is a part) is able to return a `typeinfo` object for that pointer.

Comment: @OutOfBound Note the `dynamic_cast` stuff is only an example showing that the most-derived object can be determined. You wouldn't actually pass a void pointer to `typeid()` because it will tell you "it's a void pointer." `typeid()` can be evaluated at compile time, but it *is not* evaluated at compile time when the operand is a reference to a polymorphic type.

Comment: @OutOfBound [Here's an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a64d33dc3bd75015) showing `typeid()` in action.  The `typeid()` evaluations for `*pa`, `*pb`, `ra`, and `rb` must be done at runtime (well, unless the compiler is smart enough to statically analyze the code to determine the concrete type of object the pointers/references refer to, but that is an optimization).

Answer (score 0):

`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` creates a compile-time determined string. `A` doesn't know (and, critically, *doesn't care*) whether anything actually eventually derives from it or not. It just creates a function that prints out `"virtual void A::print()"`.

If you want a function like this to correctly identify the name of the class calling it, one option is to maintain the name as a query-able object associated with the base class.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void print() {printf("(%s) : %s", get_name(), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);}
    virtual const char * get_name() {return "A";}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual const char * get_name() {return "B";}
};
```

The suggestion in the comments of using `typeid` to get the dynamic name would probably also work, but I've *never* used `typeid` before, so I can't personally vouch for its effectiveness.